# Why Conditional Probability is used

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**Question:**
Parcels from sender 'S' to receiver 'R' pass sequentially through 2 post-offices.
Each post-office has probability `1/5` of losing an incoming parcel, independently of all other parcels.
Given that a parcel is lost,  what is the probability that it was lost by the second post-office.

Why do we have to use conditional probability in this problem?
Shouldn't the answer just be:
`P(lost at 2nd) = P(not lost at 1st) * P(lost at 2nd)` 
`P(lost at 2nd) = 4/5 * 1/5`  
`P(lost at 2nd) = 4/25`

But the answer is `4/9`

Comment: But you already know that it was lost. Your working does not factor in that given condition.

Comment: @MathLover Doesn't `P(not lost at 1st)` factor in the condition? How should the question be if the answer has to be `4/25`

Comment: So think this way. We do not know if it is lost or not. The same question is posed. What is the probability that the second post office loses the letter? What would your answer be? The same that you gave above, correct?

Comment: Loosely speaking, say the probability of losing a mail is calculated as $p$ but now you are told $p = 1$. So all you are figuring out is the probability of which post office lost it. There is a difference.

Comment: @MathLover Ok. it somewhat makes sense.

Comment: ok let me add a working. See if that helps clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your question, see if this helps.

Say there are $100$ letters sent.

You expect first post office to lose $20$ letters $( = \frac{1}{5} \times 100)$.

You expect second post office to lose another $16$ letters $( = \frac{1}{5} \times (100-20)$).

So we expect $64$ letters to reach and $36$ letters to be lost.

Now we are told that our sample space is no more $100$ letters. It is those $36$ letters that are lost.

Probability that it is Post office $2$ that loses the letter if the letter is lost

$\displaystyle  = \frac{16}{36} = \frac{4}{9}$

Answer (score 1):

P(lost somewhere) $=1-(4/5)^2=9/25$

P(lost at second | lost somewhere) $=\frac{4/25}{9/25}=4/9$

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional probability because of the way the question was phrased.

You also need to actually understand the question. It's not about the probability that a package gets lost, nor the that a randomly chosen package gets lost by the second post office. It's about only those parcels that actually are lost.

$$
\begin{array}{|ccccccc|}
\hline
& & \text{lost by 1st p.o.} & & & & \frac 1 5 = \frac 5 {25} \\ & \nearrow \\ \text{start} & & & & & \text{lost by 2nd p.o.} & \frac 4 5 \times \frac 1 5 = \frac 4 {25} \\
& \searrow & & & \nearrow \\
& & \text{not lost by 1st p.o.} \\
& & & & \searrow \\
& & & & & \text{not lost by 2nd p.o.} & \frac 4 5 \times \frac 4 5 = \frac{16}{25} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
The probability of being lost is $\dfrac{5+4}{25}.$

Among those $9$ cases out of $25$ that are lost, $5$ are lost by the first post office and $4$ by the second.

Or you can express it like this: Suppose $25$ parcels are mailed. The $5$ are lost by the first post office, so $20$ go on to the second. Of those $20$ the number lost by the second post office is $4$. Thus $9$ parcels have been lost: $5$ by the first post office and $4$ by the second.